# Java database question homework problem

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have to write a Java program that creates a Car table with car manufacturers, models, model years, and fuel efficiency ratings. Insert several cars. Print out the average fuel efficiency. Use `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT`, and `SELECT AVG SQL` commands.

This is a homework question I am having trouble starting. 
This has to be done solely in UNIX, like using mysql in a unix shell and writing the java code in the shell which I can do. I have also figured out how to make tables in the shell using mysql. I have the JDBC driver and access to mysql in unix. The problem is, is how to write the code to connect to the database (I have a url, username, and password). If you could help me with the code, I would greatly appreciate it. The shell I am running on has the JDBC driver built in and ready to use.  This is what I have done, but I am not sure if its how you do it.

```
String userName = "user name";
String password = "user password";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://Hostname/DatabaseName";
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
```

Please help walking me through this with some code examples. Thanks.

Comment: [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The JDBC tutorial is good, but you will only need 5% from there, and filtering out what you need is probably hard. A view simple lines that should get you started:

```
    Class.forName(...);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

    stat.execute("create table test(id int primary key, name varchar(255))");
    stat.execute("insert into test values(1, 'Hello')");
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from test");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
    }
    rs.close();
    stat.close();
    conn.close();
```

In addition to that, you will also need `PreparedStatement`:

```
    PreparedStatement prep;
    prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into account(name) values(?)");
    prep.setString(1, "Joe");
    prep.execute();
    prep.close();
```